# Showing $X^{-1}(\mathcal F^\prime)$ is $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, self-study, sigma-algebra

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ and $(\Omega^\prime,\mathcal F^\prime)$ be two measurable spaces and $X:\Omega \to \Omega^\prime  $, show that $X^{-1}(\mathcal F^\prime)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that I must show three things, so I think first I write the definition of $X^{-1}(\mathcal F^\prime)$ and then I check the properties.

Comment: Three properties, three things to check: which of these is causing you difficulties?

Comment: @whuber.you are only give to me the definition of $X^{-1}(\mathcal F^\prime)$

Comment: Your comment is ungrammatical so I'm not sure what it is stating (or asking). If you need a definition of the pullback of a sigma algebra, then you can start with this one: $A\in X^{-1}(\mathcal F^\prime)$ if and only if $\{X(a)|a\in A\}\in \mathcal F^\prime.$